# e2e end to end, integration tests in ReactJS

Tags: testing, integration-testing, reactjs

While ReactJS homepage mentions clearly that Jest is the way to go about unit tests, it says nothing about higher level integration tests (or e2e, as they are called in Angular world).

I'm quite unfamiliar with testing actually. So what kind of tools can I use for this? I've heard about selenium, but it's a blurry picture for me.

Comment: Take a look at the scenario described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417207/integration-acceptance-testing-of-a-reactjs-app

Comment: I've just tested a React application using Nightwatch. It's a layer on top of Selenium which reveals a more accessible API without the hassle of lower level Selenium setup. However, if you need more granular control, you may find that access to Selenium directly is more useful. Give it a shot. http://nightwatchjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/). Cypress is most often compared to Selenium; however, Cypress is both fundamentally and architecturally different. Cypress is not constrained by the same restrictions as Selenium.

This enables you to write faster, easier and more reliable tests.